# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'. Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use an Azure Function to generate a SAS token. The import statement is failing.

```
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import generate_container_sas
```

with

```
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'. 
Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core 
Tools\workers\python\3.8\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\ 
dispatcher.py", line 266, in _handle__function_load_request
func = loader.load_function(
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core 
Tools\workers\python\3.8\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\ 
wrappers.py", line 34, in call
raise extend_exception_message(e, message)
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core 
Tools\workers\python\3.8\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\ 
wrappers.py", line 32, in call
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core 
Tools\workers\python\3.8\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\ 
loader.py", line 76, in load_function
mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
File "C:\Users\2259252\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ 
importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "C:\Projects\Additive\SkyforgeAPI\FileAPI\RequestFileUpload\ 
__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from azure.storage.blob import generate_container_sas.
```

Package is installed in the venv

```
$ .venv/Scripts/python -m pip freeze
azure-core==1.9.0
azure-functions==1.5.0
azure-storage-blob==12.6.0
...
```

My requirements.txt file:

```
azure-functions
azure-storage-blob==12.6.0
```

What am I missing?

Closest [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383741/importerror-no-module-named-azure-storage-blob-when-doing-syncdb)

Comment: Is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61707234/azure-function-modulenotfounderror-in-python-script) helpful for you?

Comment: @JosephXu - I have a requirements.txt that I added to the question

Comment: Can it run successfully if you try it locally?

Comment: No, if I use `func start` locally I get the same error.

Comment: According to the error message, maybe you can use anaconda to create a python3.8 env locally to run the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you description, it seems you are based on global environment instead of running in `.venv` environment.

Please pay attention to this:

[image]

If you are based on Windows OS, then I think you need to use below command:

`cd .venv`

then

`.\Scripts\activate.bat`

After all, run

`cd ..`

`func host start`

After that, It works fine on my side.

Comment: Thanks, azure tools had created a venv for me but I had to activate it with source .venv/Scripts/activate.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the issue is similar to the one [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/477)

At the moment only python3.7 is supported for this version of azure-storage-blob