# Azure Functions fails running when deployed

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm new here, sorry if the post is incomplete.

I'm trying to deploy a python script on azure that interacts with blobs.
The script works fine in local : i can interact with my storage account, upload & download blobs...
But when I deploy my function on azure, it won't run.
The logs says no module named azure.storage exists.

Thing is, on my computer i had to pip install this module.

Should i add this module on azure web ?
How am I supposed to do such a thing ?

I'm developping on Visual Studio Code using python 3.6.5.

Error listed in the invocations Details :

```
Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'. Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 309, in _handle__function_load_request func_request.metadata.entry_point) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 42, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 85, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "/home/site/wwwroot/HttpTriggerTest/__init__.py", line 3, in <module> import HttpTriggerTest.dependance1 as dependance1 File "/home/site/wwwroot/HttpTriggerTest/__init__.py", line 4, in <module> import azure.storage.blob
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sol 1 :** try setting environment variable **FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME** to **python**

**Sol 2:** try adding **azure.storage** to your **requirements.txt** file

For further refer [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383741/importerror-no-module-named-azure-storage-blob-when-doing-syncdb), [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643865/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-azure-storage-azure-function),[Ref3](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/819).

Comment: Thank you RithwikBojja-MT for your quick answer.

I checked FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME in the configuration but it was already 'python'.

So i checked the requirements.txtin my visual studio code project : i didn't wrote the package so it wasn't deployed on azure.
(The package i needed was azure-storage-blob if someone ask)